# Should I format my ASMX web service responses for AJAX server side or client side?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, web-services

Two parts to my question:

1. I need to format my web service responses for display on my web page.  Should I use JavaScript to format the responses or given that it’s a .NET web service format the response as HTML and then simply push it down to the client?
2. If I'm using JavaScript to manipulate the response, what datatypes should I avoid returning from a .NET web service that might not "play nice" with JavaScript?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It depends on the context. If you're returning a simple string to update a `<span>`, then I would use javascript to format it. If you're returning an RSS feed, then I would format it server side. If you're using an autocompleter for a text box, it might be better to output the html with an IHttpHandler instead.
2. If you use JSON ([ScriptService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute.aspx)) web service methods, it shouldn't matter what the .NET type is. The return value will be serialized as a [JSON](http://www.json.org/js.html) object.

Here's an excellent tutorial on [consuming JSON ASP.NET web services with jQuery](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/).